# Can we filter data stored in JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, database, posts

I am creating a website like [medium](https://medium.com). As I am new in web development I am using php ajax with mysql database and storing posts of users in JSON format.
[Click to see database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUags.png).
Titles and descriptions are inside JSON. My questions are:-

1. How can I search posts as the user enters title in search bar.
2. Should the likes and comments be stored in same JSON file (many users can comment at a same time)?
3. Different posts have different JSON will the title and descriptions be shown on google search?
4. How should I store big datas like:- title,descriptions,likes,comments so that I can filter easily from search input.

Thanks for help :)

Comment: If you want to search and filter your database content, don't store it as JSON data. Create proper tables.

Comment: Should I store thousands of words(description) in database table? What about likes and comments? Thanks :) @TangentiallyPerpendicular

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend new users review [ask] for tips on forming their questions in a way the best invites the community to provide assistance.  This question lacks focus-- you ask four questions in your post, which basically requests a full tutorial for how to implement an entire website data layer.  I'd recommend doing some research on your own, or perhaps finding a site that is more geared towards conversation and mentorship, as opposed to SO, which is intended for simple and specific Q&A.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"can you" - yes. *should you* no.

You're going to need *several* related tables, at *minimum* `articles`, `comments`, `users` and likely more as you'll want to store attachments in a different table as well. *Generally* JSON should not be used for data you wish to search/index. more store for convenience.

Example table structure. This is to get the "juices flowing" and "point you in the right direction", it should **NOT** be taken verbatim and turned into a production database.

If you use the below, if you want to search for articles that contain the word "cats" you simply use

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE content like '%cats%';
```

**articles**

| column name | column type |
| --- | --- |
| id | `int`, `autoincrement` |
| title | `varchar(255)` |
| content | `text` |
| created_by | `int`, Foreign Key `users.id` |
| created_on | `datetime`, default now |
| last_updated_by | `int`, Foreign Key `users.id` |
| last_updated_on | `datetime`, default now, change on update |

**comments**

| column name | column type |
| --- | --- |
| id | `int`, `autoincrement` |
| article_id | `int`, Foreign Key `articles.id` |
| content | `text` |
| created_by | `int`, Foreign Key `users.id` |
| created_on | `datetime`, default now |
| last_updated_by | `int`, Foreign Key `users.id` |
| last_updated_on | `datetime`, default now, change on update |

**users**

| column name | column type |
| --- | --- |
| id | `int`, `autoincrement` |
| name | `varchar(255)` |
| username | `varchar(255)` |
| email | `text` |
| password | `varchar(255)` **STORE HASHES NOT PLAINTEXT** |
| created_on | `datetime`, default now |